# Iterate through all empty array and push a default object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm very new to angular so please excuse if the answer to the question is fairly simple.  My data sctructure is such that I need to render multiple arrays of objects. In my view, all of these are displayed as forms wrapped in ng-repeat. The problem that I am running into is if any of the arrays are empty, the form will not show. Since the arrays are all different, I'd like to be able to iterate through all arrays and add default objects to those arrays which are empty. Below is an example of one of these arrays:

```
$scope.client.contacts =
    [
        { Id: 1, FistName: "firstname", LastName: "lastname", Phone: "111-111-1117", Address: "11 Address Place", City: "Lawrence", StateId: 1, Zip: "11111", Relationship: "Mother", Email: "testing@gmail.com", SystemLogin: true },
        { Id: 2, FistName: "firstname2", LastName: "lastname2", Phone: "111-111-1111", Address: "1111 Ocean Ave", City: "Brooklyn", StateId: 1, Zip: "11111", Relationship: "Grandmother", Email: "testing2@gmail.com", SystemLogin: false }
    ];
```

What would be the best and most efficient way of doing this? A jsfiddle code exmaple would be extremely helpful

Comment: `if (array.length === 0) {array.push({});}`?

Comment: Thank you. That currently what I have but looking for something that can be reused across all arrays in scope. So basically a function that iterates through all arrays and pushes new object where length == 0

Comment: So, you want a loop? It's hard to understand what the difficulty is with the information you posted.